# Half of adults are tall in the situation where there are an odd number of the adults

Tags: grammatical-number

There are seven adults, and half of them are tall. Then, it doesn’t make sense, or three and a half are tall?

But apart from the context, if we consider them as a group, not individually, can half of the group mean three and a half?

Comment: Grammar and meaning are two different things. The sentence "the green hippo jumped over the chocolate river" is a pretty ridiculous sentence in meaning, but it is grammatically fine. If you're interested in the philosophy of this, look up "colorless green ideas sleep furiously"; if you're interested in learning regular English, don't worry about it too much.

Comment: This is not an English question. It would be false in your language also.  Not everything can be halved.

Comment: @Lambie But I can’t imagine a collective noun is treated both collectively and individually in my language.

Comment: @Lambie There is a similar term 가족들 중 절반, but it means halves of my family.

Comment: Because people are not apples  or number sets.

Comment: Statistically it's possible to say that the average family has 2.5 children. What does that mean? Some families have as many as 4 or 5 children while others have just 1 or 2 kids. It doesn't mean that every family has two and a half children.  This surely must be the same in your native language, decimal points and statistics are used worldwide. [*The June 11-14, 2007 poll finds that Americans, on average, believe the ideal number of children for a family to have these days is 2.5.*](https://news.gallup.com/poll/27973/americans-25-children-ideal-family-size.aspx)

Comment: 7명의 성인이 있고 그 중 절반은 키가 큽니다. 키가 몇인가요?  This is why this isn't a question of English.  It is exactly the same as Korean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of scale and [significant figures.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

At a basic level, *one adult* indivisible. You cannot have "half of a tall adult." So if you have a group of seven adults and divide the group in half, you will **not** end up with two groups of three-and-a-half adults each. Instead you will have one group of three and one group of four; it is impossible to divide a group of an odd number of adults into two *precisely even* halves. This is an inherent property of integers, not a question of language.

You can increase the number of adults in the group while keeping the number of significant figures the same. For example, assume you now have seven *thousand* adults, and you say "half of them are tall." That means that *approximately* 3500 adults are tall, but due to the imprecision in the original number (only one significant figure) it would be incorrect to assume that *exactly* 3500 are tall and *exactly* 3500 are short. However, if you express the division as a percentage you can use additional significant figures to constrain the answer, for example by saying "There are 7000 adults, and 50.00% of them are tall."

But you still cannot have half a person. It does not make sense to say "There are 7001 adults, and 50.00% of them are tall" because that leaves you with 3500.5 tall adults, and that does not make any sense. In that case, better to say simply "half of them are tall" (implying "*about* half of them are tall"). Better yet would be to explicitly qualify the adjective "half" to make it clear that you are not claiming precision, and say "about half" in the first place instead of implying it.

Comment: Even though considering them as a group, can’t I indicate three and a half?

Comment: Absolutely not @Gate. How can half-a-person be tall? Or how can a person be half-tall? It makes no sense. Think about what you actually mean (either three or four of them are tall) and say that.

Comment: I don't understand why you fell for this and I object to the bounty. Can't even vote to close.

Comment: @randomhead So I said “apart from the context.” I’m sorry if I messed around.

Comment: @Gate I have revised my answer to add details on why "half of seven adults" is not 3.5 adults.

Comment: @randomhead I mean If I ate half of a bundle of seven apples, then it can’t mean I ate three and a half of the bundle of apples?

Comment: @randomhead I mean even if they are apples not people?

Comment: @GatePending you can cut up apples; you can't cut up people,or at least not without severe consequences.  So people are indivisible unlike apples.  That said, if you had a bag of apples, told me you'd eaten half, and I found that the bag originally contained 7, I wouldn't be surprised to learn you'd eaten 3 or 4.  Similarly we can talk about "the big half" and "the little half", and make sense, while annoying logicians.  Rounding may be assumed.

Comment: @Chris H I mean 3.5 apples left…

Comment: @GatePending as I said, you can cut up apples, so you can eat 3.5=0.5*7.  But half can also mean "approximately half", i.e. 3 or 4 apples - multilpe meanings . In the case of indivisible living people it must be interpreted as approximately half.

Comment: @Chris H Thank you.

Comment: This is a question about logic, not English. Great answer if the OP wanted to know the meaning of 3.5 adults but that's not the question being asked.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I tried to address that at the end of my answer. Do you have any suggestions on improvements?

Comment: If I felt like answering, I might have geared towards statistics, saying something like e.g 3.5 adults are 205cm tall...  but that is very different from saying 3 and a half adults in a room of 11 adults are tall. Your answer is clear and well-written but IMO it's about logic not language. And I suspect the OP is trolling us a bit.